# Have SSHD listen to another port on Centos with SELinux running

Tags: centos, ssh, selinux

I have a Centos VM running with SELinux enabled. I wish to have sshd listen to another port --- says, 993. I've modified the sshd_config file to listen to another port, but SELinux is getting in the way. I don't want to disable SELinux. How do I tell SELinux that it's okay for sshd to be reading TCP connections on port 993?

The correct command to use is `semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 993` but I cannot use that command because port 993 is already in use in another policy:

```
[centos@timedb ~]$ semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 993
ValueError: SELinux policy is not managed or store cannot be accessed.
[centos@timedb ~]$
```

But I cannot delete that port in the policy because it is part of the base policy:

```
[centos@timedb ~]$ sudo semanage port -l|grep 993
pop_port_t                     tcp      106, 109, 110, 143, 220, 993, 995, 1109, 10993
[centos@timedb ~]$ sudo semanage port -d -t pop_port_t -p tcp 993
ValueError: Port tcp/993 is defined in policy, cannot be deleted
[centos@timedb ~]$
```

I need to use a port that is already defined becasue I am upstream from a middlebox that only allows connections on ports allocated to specified services, and port 22 is blocked.

Answer (score 4):

Use `semanage(8)` to allow it.

```
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 993
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this need to be done once, or on every boot?

Comment: I have clarified question regarding my specific problem.